# When should I replace kanji with hiragana?

Tags: kanji, hiragana

When should I write 海山 and when should I write うみやま?

Comment: Usually it's OK for Hiragana.

Answer (score 25):

Well, it's *always* safe to use the hiragana.  You could technically write Japanese entirely in kana, although it would become very difficult to read and lack the context clues provided by kanji.

If `海山` is someone's (family) name, first make sure it is really pronounced as `うみやま` because [it could have some other pronunciation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5532/78).  Secondly, [depending on the context for which you're writing the name](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5316/78), you have several different options.

If you're using `海山` to just mean "the sea and mountains" (or the phrase `海山の恩`), you can, and probably should use kanji.

So what's the rationale for replacing kanji with hiragana?  Well, if you don't know how to write the kanji, you can always fall back to hiragana as I mentioned.  Another rationale would be writing something like a children's book.  Since young children may not know kanji, or how to read a certain kanji, the author may use hiragana (although I believe `海` and `山` are likely taught at a young age).

And although you didn't ask the inverse question, I'll answer it anyway.  What's the rationale for using kanji instead of all kana?  As I said, ease of reading.  Once you start learning kanji, reading anything written in all kana can be "difficult"; not that it's hard, but certainly can take longer.  Kanji also gives context.  Japanese has **many** homonyms, so seeing something written in kanji can give you a reasonable, if not exact understanding of what it means.  For example, if I write the word `いし`, you don't know if I mean "rock" (`石`), "doctor" (`医師`), "will/volition" (`意志`), or any of the many other words with that pronunciation.

Comment: The one thing I would add is that hiragana can also be used in writing when there is already too much kanji being used. This is to make it look less stuffy and formal. In that situation, it is more a style issue than a grammar one.

Answer (score 5):

Hiragana is a script, which in normal Japanese texts is used alongside kanji and katakana.

Hiragana is usually used for grammatical functions (e.g., particles, verb inflections, etc.) and for words for which there doesn't exist kanji, or for words whose kanji are non-standard.

海山 would usually be written in kanji. However, 海山 could in principle also be read かいさん (or かいざん, see dainichi's comment below), which may be a reason for writing it with furigana (like so [海山]{うみやま}) or with hiragana alone, for example in books for primary school kids.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: "could in principle also be read かいさん" could be misleading, since 海山{かいざん} seems to be an existing word (I admit I didn't know till I looked it up).

Comment: @dainichi Thanks, I had tried only WWWJDIC and it wasn't listed in there. Here's a link for anyone who is curious: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/35942/m0u/

Comment: I heard Japanese is more simplified than Chinese, but apparently it's even worse...

Comment: Both more and less simplified. Usually only those characters which are used for sound rather than meaning are replaced with hiragana. Those characters which are there to convey meaning, stay (in traditional form!). I quite like Japanese for that. (Have a look at [Man'yogana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dgana) to see why and how this happened.)