# Writing できました as 出来ました

Tags: kanji, readings, japanese-to-english

I came across a tweet of an illustration with the caption "出来ました"

https://twitter.com/sakura77722/status/1461636114930798594

When writing the verb できる as 出来る does it still mean things like "could do/done"? Does using kanji for this verb change the meaning or implication?

Comment: No, it doesn't, just a matter of style.

Comment: Related (or duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17388/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15141/9831

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly but I think it doesn't matter if you write it with Kanji or not.

jisho.org shows directly the Kanji characters when you look up the verb.

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 0):

できました and 出来ました are the same, but 出来ました is not frequently used.
Japanese don't usually use kanji on words that has grammatical function. 生きていく is not usually written as 生きて行く. Anyways, 出来ました and できました can be in grammatical function and other functions. In this case, just the popularity of use that matters.