# How do I find out the written form of a notable person given their name's pronunciation?

Tags: names

Related question: [How do you write someone's name if you don't know what kanji to use?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/how-do-you-write-someones-name-if-you-dont-know-what-kanji-to-use) , but that's for the name of a non-notable person.

I'd like to know the Japanese name of someone who's been in the news of English-language media (Masaaki Imaeda). He doesn't have an English-language Wikipedia article yet, so I can't just look him up and see what the Japanese language edition has as his name.

I tried googling "まさあき いまえだ シドニー", but that didn't seem to get many useful results. Even "今枝正明 シドニー" mainly gave results in Chinese.

(I'm assuming that he's been covered in Japanese-language media, which may not be the case)

He was born in Japan and came to Australia in [1973](http://www.smh.com.au/nsw/slum-lord-fined-215000-after-fire-guts-illegal-housing-setup-in-alexandria-20170310-guv3pu.html), and was born in [1951 or 1950](http://www.news.com.au/national/crime/photographs-reveal-for-the-first-time-the-secret-sex-lair-where-slumlord-pervert-masaaki-imaeda-spied-on-tenants/news-story/31cfd10f20e11412f2f5ae29cc3dfb48), so he would have been a young adult when he came to Australia.

Comment: Is he a Japanese citizen living in Australia or a (naturalized) Japanese-Australian?  If the latter were the case, his name would generally be written in katakana in the Japanese media.  Here is an example: https://tsuiran.jp/word/998715/hourly?t=1495710000

Comment: @l'électeur added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that person is really [notable](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E7%89%B9%E7%AD%86%E6%80%A7_(%E4%BA%BA%E7%89%A9)) enough in Japanese, the hiragana name should always be in his/her article on Japanese Wikipedia, so you should be able to find the kanji name with his/her hiragana name by using Google or Wikipedia search. [Wikipedia:スタイルマニュアル (人物伝)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB_(%E4%BA%BA%E7%89%A9%E4%BC%9D)#.E5.90.8D.E5.89.8D.E3.81.A8.E8.AA.AD.E3.81.BF.E4.BB.AE.E5.90.8D) says:

> 名前の直後に括弧（）をつけ、最初に読み仮名を記載してください。

Example:

[image]

If that person is not that notable, practically, all you can do is make random guesses on kanji and keep googling until you hit something.